# Snowsql two digit century start date cast issue

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

I want a result `2000-02-05` with below query in snowsql.

```
alter session set  TWO_DIGIT_CENTURY_START=2000;
select cast ('05-FEB-00' as date) from dual;
```

But I am getting `0001-02-05`. 
I am using existing script to load date in snowflake which works for oracle. I know I can get expected result using to_date function but I don't want to do so. If I have to then I have change many place in script which is hectic.

I want solution using cast function. Do anyone know what is happening here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You first need to specify the non-default date format for your input data.  In the case of the example above:

```
alter session set date_input_format = 'DD-MON-YY';
```

Then

```
alter session set  TWO_DIGIT_CENTURY_START=2000;
select cast ('05-FEB-00' as date) from dual;
```

yields:

2000-02-05

Comment: Note, TWO_DIGIT_CENTURY_START is not strictly needed for this date, 00 will still translate to 2000 with the default setting.